# Which spaces have trivial K-theory?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

What is known about spaces $X$ with the property that $K^*(\text{point})\to K^*(X)$ is an isomorphism?

The same question for $K$-homology $K_*(X)\to K_*(\text{point})$; I don't even know whether these conditions are equivalent.

Note that replacing $K$-theory with integral homology one gets very interesting (I think) class of spaces, studied in "[Acyclic spaces](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~farjoun/acyclic%20spaces.pdf)" by E. Dror.

Comment: All acyclic spaces have trivial K-theory (it's a simple argument with the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence), but I think you get more things

Comment: @DenisNardin I would rather think that all K-trivial spaces would be acyclic, while K-theory could distinguish more spaces than "ordinary" homology. I just don't know enough, but I think the Adams $e$-invariant detects K-theory classes killed by the Chern character, cannot one find something along these lines?

Comment: I don’t know a characterization, but it’s bigger than you might expect: K(Z/p, 2) is such a space.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე A space is acyclic iff its suspension spectrum is contractible (in fact iff its second suspension is contractible), hence all (co)homology theory have trivial values on acyclic spaces

Comment: @EricPeterson Sorry I don't have enough skills to compute this. Can you explain why?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე you can either prove this directly (a good exercise using the bar spectral sequence), or note that it follows from a result of Ravenel-Wilson: their results (using the bar spectral sequence) give that $(KU^\wedge_p \wedge \Sigma^\infty K(\mathbf{Z}/p^i, n))^\wedge_p$ vanishes for n>1 and all i. Coupled with the arithmetic fracture square and the fact that $KU_\mathbf{Q} \wedge \Sigma^\infty K(\mathbf{Z}/p^i, n)$ is contractible (the rationalization of $K(\mathbf{Z}/p^i, n)$ is contractible), you can conclude $KU$-acyclicity for $K(\mathbf{Z}/p^i, n)$ with n>1 and all i.

Comment: @skd Thanks a lot, surely I would never figure this out! One question - in principle something might have trivial $p$-completion but nontrivial $p$-localization, no? Or is this irrelevant here?

Comment: Sure, just take any rational object.

Comment: @skd Well sorry I should then also add rationally trivial, since this is what happens in your situation.

Comment: If a rationally trivial space has trivial p-completion for all p, then it is contractible. I'm a little worried that some connectivity assumption might be missing, but I'm fairly confident this is true in the simply-connected case.

Comment: @skd I see, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll just give an answer for finite complexes $X$. The condition $\widetilde{K}^*(X)=0$ only depends on the suspension spectrum of $X$ so this is naturally regarded as a question in stable homotopy theory.  The condition also implies that $\widetilde{H}^*(X;\mathbb{Q})=0$ and thus that $n.1_X=0$ as a stable map for some $n>0$.  From this it follows that $X$ splits stably as a wedge of finitely many $p$-torsion finite spectra for different primes $p$, so we are really looking at a question in $p$-local stable homotopy theory.  The condition $\widetilde{K}^*(X)=0$ then says that $X$ has chromatic type at least two.  For the general theory of chromatic type of finite spectra you can read Ravenel's book "Nilpotence in stable homotopy theory".  For type two, it is possible to be a little more explicit than for higher types.  For example, Adams constructed a certain self-map of the mod $p$ Moore spectrum which induces an isomorphism in $K$-theory, so the cofibre of that map has type two.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the work about $v_n$-local unstable homotopy theory, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06325

Comment: Is there a non-acyclic closed manifold with vanishing reduced K-theory? For oriented, this is clearly not possible because of rational homology, but there might be a non-oriented example?